# how to update mongo db all records in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have mongo db collection which stores the JSON. 
By mistakenly,  one element value was updated wrong in all records of a collection.

How i will update the particular element ?

My json is like

```
{
status:
   {
     name:"john",
     value: "12345678903333.444"
   }
}
```

here the value property value should be long field, value  will be replaced by

```
{
status:
   {
     "name":"john",
     "value": 1234567890
  }
}
```

value should be trimmed as first 10 character of existing value.

After updating(from @mickl answer),
[image: different format - other than numeric]

Converting to Int also got error!
[image: Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operator with [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/) to convert string to number and then redirect aggregation results into the same collection using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) (which will basically update all its documents), Try in Mongo shell:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "status.value": { $toDouble: { $substr: [ "$status.value", 0, 10 ] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "col"
    }
])
```

Or in C# code:

```
var addFieldsBody = "{ $addFields: { \"status.value\": { $toDouble: { $substr: [ \"$status.value\", 0, 10 ] } } } }";

Col.Aggregate()
   .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse(addFieldsBody))
   .Out("col");
```

Comment: Thanks @mickl for your reply. I have tried your query in Mongo shell . Records are  updated. but it shows different format. I have attached screen in question.

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy is status.value string or number in your database ?

Comment: Existing value is string. but i want to update it as int. Is it possible?

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy seems like you have some values in scientific notation so I modified my answer and simply replaced $toInt with $toDouble (should handle such format)